# $\int_x^a \frac {f^{n+2}(t)}{n+1!}(x-t)^{n+1}dt = \frac {f^{n+1}(K)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1}$

Tags: calculus

In the proof of taylor's theorem in one variable in wikipedia the following equality is presented:

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_Theorem/One_Variable (Second last line to the last line of the first proof).

$\int_x^a \frac {f^{n+2}(t)}{n+1!}(x-t)^{n+1}dt = \frac {f^{n+1}(K)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1}$ for some $K \in (a,b) $. Any insights to explain this equality appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof in Wikipedia is muddled.  The final integration by parts is unnecessary for deriving the Cauchy form of the remainder $R_n$ from the integral form.  Furthermore, the statement that " ... the last integral can be solved immediately ... " with reference to

$$\tag{*}\int_a^x \frac{f^{(n+2)}(t)}{(n+1)!}(x - t)^{n+1} \, dt$$

is, at best, ambiguous.  Notice, also, that this is the integral form for the remainder $R_{n+1}$ not $R_n$.

Assuming $f^{(n+1)}$ is continuous and since $(x - t)^{n} \geqslant 0$ for $t \in [a,x]$, we can apply the (second) mean value theorem for integrals to obtain $K \in [a,x]$ such that

$$R_n = \int_a^x \frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{n!}(x - t)^{n} \, dt = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(K)}{n!} \int_a^x (x - t)^{n} \, dt \\ = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(K)}{(n+1)!}  (x - a)^{n+1}. $$

This is the correct Cauchy form of the remainder $R_n$ and cannot be obtained from (*) without reversing the final integration by parts in the Wikepedia proof.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help.